# What are secure ways of sharing a server (ssh+LAMP) with friends?

Tags: apache-2.2, linux, shared-hosting, virtualhost

What is the best way to share a virtual server with friends? More precisely, I have the following assets:

- A virtual private server (Debian Lenny) with root access for myself, running...

  - SSH
  - apache2
  - mysql
- Some unused disk space
- Some friends in need of hosting

#### The problem

I would now like to do the following:

- Hosting one or several domains per friend
- My friends should have *full access* to their domains, including running PHP scripts, for example
- My friends should not be able to poke around in other directories
- The security of my server should not be compromised by faulty PHP scripts

To clarify: I do *trust* my friends in the sense that they are not trying to do something evil with their access. I just do not trust the programs they are going to run.

So, what are your recommendations for establishing such a scenario?

#### Partial solution

I already came up with the following plan:

- Add `chroot`ed SSH users for my friends
- Add Apache vhosts per user (point the directories to subdirectories of the homedirectories, i.e. `/home/alice/example.com`, `/home/bob/example.net`, etc.

But how can I enforce a `chroot`-like environment for the scripts they are running within these vhosts? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I would look into one of the many prebuilt packages to do shared hosting. I use ispCP myself, but plesk is another popular one. Very frequently, shell access is not required, so a prebuilt package makes life simpler.

Comment: @Richard: Good idea, but this seems to be too much hassle for only a handful of users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make php scripts executed with uid of your friend aka user,
checkout google for suphp

Comment: OK, this seems quite interesting. However, it seems that there are severe performance penalties. Did you try suPHP for yourself already and can comment on this claim?

Comment: ISPcp uses something along those lines I'm running my server virtualized and haven't been disappointed by the performance.

Comment: I have decided to try both options and see which suits best (in terms of performance and ease of use). Thanks for the answers!